# Deshabilitar clonado de repositorio en cada ejecución con Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, pipeline

Tengo un problema con jenkins y mi repositorio remoto.

Mi repositorio es un workspace con muchas carpetas , cada una de ellas es un programa/test.
El problema es que cada vez que ejecuto un job desde jenkins, se me crea una carpeta local con el nombre del job y con todo el repositorio dentro de ella, si lanzo otro job, se me crea otra carpeta y dentro de ella todo el repositorio clonado. No se a que se debe ya que he trabajado con jenkins en otras ocasiones y nunca me he encontrado algo asi.

Mi jenkins esta configurado como pipeline, para que coja el repositorio de github y ejecute un jenkinsfile. Pero ninguna configuración extra, quizas haya alguna opcion que desconozco para que no clone?
Diria que no es por el pipeline ya que no he añadido el “git clone” en el, puede ser por usar de agente un docker?
Deberia deshabilitar el clonado de alguna manera o es un problema de organización de repositorio, y por cada job deberia crear un repositorio diferente??

Gracias por responder y la guia Alfabravo!

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx. Suena a que tu pipeline en Jenkins clona el repo cada vez (suena razonable) para procesar el código. Todo depende de la configuración que tengas en Jenkins, de la definición del pipeline y demás elementos asociados a esa ejecución. Normalmente Jenkins limpia el workspace para un mismo pipeline si se lo indicas, pero no sabemos cómo tienes configurado tu Jenkins.
Edita tu pregunta y añade los detalles relevantes para que no tengamos que adivinar ;)

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto el problema;

La función deleteDir borra de forma recursiva el directorio actual y su contenido. De esta manera no se guarda en nuestro local el workspace cada vez que lancemos un job.